# PipBuilder with Ocean 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ocean, petrel

I'm working with Petrel and Ocean 2013 and am trying to use the PipBuilder in Visual Studio 2010 to build a PIP file for a plug-in I'm working on.  Right now, all I'm trying to do is figure out how to get the "New PipBuilder" option in VS to accept a project, so I've just thrown together the "Make your first Plug-in" project found in Schlumberger's documentation to see if I can just get the process down for setting this up before I start to change my actual plug-in.

My problem is that I always get the, "The wizard did not find any Plug-in assemblies..." error, even though I've pointed the wizard at all sorts of places--the project directory, the project bin directory (which is where I assume the "assemblies" it's talking about would be).  There's not a whole lot of documentation or help I can find online for this Ocean/Petrel stuff, so I was wondering if anyone knew exactly where this wizard is supposed to be pointing in order to allow it to accept a project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what needs to happen is you make a new PipBuilder project *using the same solution* as the plug-in you're working on.  That is to say, you make a new plug-in, do all the things you need to do, build said plugin, then, instead of using a whole new VS instance to make a PipBuilder, with your plugin project up, you do File->New->Project->PipBuilder.

I thought you had to do what you do for every other kind of project: make a new one and point it at the location of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you build the VS project that contains your plug-in before you run the PIPBuilder wizard. 
Also, make sure that your VS project for the plug-in has a class that derives from the Plugin class that defines your plug-in. It will have a Modules property that refers to your class that implements IModule where the real work of your plug-in begins.

Comment: I do have these things.  There's a Module, Plugin, and one Workstep.  Like I said, this is just a simple example plugin for me to figure this out.  I do build and get a dll dropped in my bin directory, as expected, but no matter where I point the PipBuilder wizard it always errors.